# My example angular application is throwing an error that says "Property 'name' does not exist on type 'Employee[]'."

Tags: angular

I am trying to recreate an example angular application for practice learning and I am getting an error that says "Property 'name' does not exist on type 'Employee[]'.". I have created an interface 'Employee' that has a string variable 'name'.

```
    export interface Employee {`
        id: number;
        name: string;
        email: string;
        jobTitle: string;
        phone: string;
        imageUrl: string;
        employeeCode: string;
    }
```

My app.component looks like this:

```
    import { HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { Employee } from './employee';
    import { EmployeeService } from './employee.service';
    
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-root',
      templateUrl: './app.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
    })
    export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
      public employees: Employee[];
    
    constructor(private employeeService: EmployeeService){
    }
    
    ngOnInit() {
      this.getEmployees();
    }
    
    public getEmployees(): void {
      this.employeeService.getEmployees().subscribe(
        (response: Employee[]) => {
          this.employees = response;
        },
        (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
          alert(error.message);
        }
      )
    }
    
    }
```

And my app.component.html looks like this:

```
    <div *ngFor="let employee of employees" >
      <div>{{employee.name}}</div>
    </div>
```

In the HTML, when I type in 'employee.' it is not registering the name as a variable in the Employee interface and is throwing an error saying that the property 'name' does not exist on type Employee[]. I am new at this and am not quite sure what I am doing wrong here. Any help is much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: The error message clearly states that you are trying to access the property `name` of an Array. Are you sure you are not using `{{ employees.name }}` in your jsx?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the API calls done to the backend are done asynchronously thus your array is not populated with the values but the code for its rendering already runs.
There are few solution points that we can do

1. We can make the employee property a Promise and use an async pipe on it in the HTML Template.
2. We can use async-await on the API function calls.
3. We can render the component only after component load using a flag.

Executing the 3rd Solution here ->

In the Ts File ->

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  public employees: Employee[];
  public listLoaded = false;             // Flag for api Load Detection.

constructor(private employeeService: EmployeeService){
}

ngOnInit() {
  this.getEmployees();
}

public getEmployees(): void {
  this.employeeService.getEmployees().subscribe(
    (response: Employee[]) => {
      this.employees = response;
      this.listLoaded = true;             // Setting Flag on List Load
    },
    (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
      alert(error.message);
    }
  )
}

}
```

In Html File ->

```
<div *ngIf='listLoaded'>
<div *ngFor="let employee of employees" >
  <div>{{employee.name}}</div>
</div>
</div>
```